# Web-scraping advice/suggestions

Tags: php, python, web-scraping

This is my first attempt at scraping. There is a website with a search function that I would like to use.

When I do a search, the search details aren't shown in the website url. When I inspect the element and look at the Network tab, the request url stays the same (**`method:post`**), but when I looked at the bottom, in the ***`Form Data`*** section, I clicked view source and there were my search details in url form.

My question is:

If the **request url = `http://somewebsite.com/search`**
and the **form data source = `startDate=09.07.2016&endDate=10.07.2016`**

How can I connect the two to pull data for scraping? I'm new to scraping, so if I'm going about this wrong, please tell me.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that you will find that the major search engines have actively made what you are attempting to do more challenging than it was in years past. They do, however, offer APIs to allow searches. These will generally require you to subscribe and pay for some level of access to the API. If you do choose to persist with attempting to scrape, be prepared to be challenged by CAPTCHAs very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

scraping is bad practice, but in some cases it is the only way to get something.
If you are scraping some website consider be gentle and don't make 1m requests in a day.

Basically you will need to use php curl fucntion and pass post fields

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com/search");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('postvar1'=>'value1')));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$html = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks AucT. I was also considering doing it in python. Looks like cURL is a better option. What do you think? And no, I'm not planning on doing a gazillion requests a day, just a handful. :)

Comment: you can do it in any language, that supports curl. Just google curl post %language%.

Answer (score 1):

## Ethics

Using a bot to get at the content of sites can be beneficial to you and the site you're scraping. You can use the data to refer to content of the site, like search engines do. Sometimes you might want to provide a service to user that the original website doesn't offer.

However, sometimes scraping is used for nefarious purposes. Stealing content, using the computer resources of others, or worse.

It is not clear what intention you have. Helping you, might be unethical. I'm not saying it is, but it could be. I don't understand 'AucT', saying it is bad practice and then give an answer. What is that all about?

Two notes:

1. Search results take more resources to generate than most other webpages. They are especially vulnerable to denial-of-service attacks.
2. I run serveral sites, and I have notices that a large amount of traffic is caused by bots. It is literally costing me money. Some sites have more traffic from bots than from people. It is getting out of hand, and I had to invest quite a bit of time to get the problem under control. Bots that don't respect bandwidth limits are blocked by me, permanently. I do, of course, allow friendly bots.

Comment: Hey KIKO. Thanks for your answer. No, I'm not intending on stealing information. I'm actually intending on doing what you suggested at the beginning of your answer, "to provide a service to users that the original website doesn't offer." I don't want anyone to question their ethics because I asked a question on how to attempt scraping.

Comment: If your intentions are good, I assume you have contacted the website you are going to scrape and agreed with them that it is ok? Any content provider would appreciate that. If you provide them with your unique 'browser string' they can also monitor your usage. Doing so can make your service more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple html dom http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
<?php
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$request = array(
        'http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query(array(
                        'startDate' => '09.07.2016',
                        'endDate' => '10.07.2016'
                )),
        )
);
$url = "http://somewebsite.com/search";
$context = stream_context_create($request);
$html = file_get_html($url, false, $context);
?>
```